# Detect USB pendrive plugging in with applescript

Tags: applescript, automator

I want to execute automator script when user plug in a pendrive with specific name. 
How can I do it?

Comment: Nothing, I don't know where to start. Why do you think I'm asking here.

Comment: I think you are posting here because you are mistaken about what this place is. Here, you are supposed to do some work yourself and then when you get stuck. We aren't here to look for resources on a subject for you, when you can do the same thing yourself.

Comment: If you can not answer, don't waste your time writing useless comments, Jasper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applescript and automator cannot do this. However **launchd** can. Launchd can watch folders, and if something changes in the folder then launched will run your command. In your case you would want to watch the /Volumes folder. When you mount the USB drive it's mount point will be that folder. Therefore you need to write yourself a launchd plist file, and your command could be to run your automator script. Just google for more info on launchd. I did a quick search and [this link](http://www.macresearch.org/tutorial_backups_with_launchd) gives most of the information you need.

Comment: I added another answer to this question, as I think you can do this with Automator. Can you let me know if I missed something?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, I believe that Applescript can in fact do what you want. A `Folder Action` listening to the `Volumes` directory (as per [Auto-Detect Mounted Volumes](http://automatorworld.com/archives/auto-detect-mounted-volumes/)) will run any time a volume is mounted. You can then run a shell script (or some other method) that detects if the mounted drive is your drive, and run your workflow if so (or perhaps more easily, exit if not).